# Function body.getReader() doesnt work on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, next.js, nest

I'm trying to deploy a project on **ubuntu server 22.04**. Im using **Next.js + Nest.js**
Encountered a problem where my Fetch API works differently, on my localhost (*macOS*) everything works fine and i receive chunks of response, however when i deployed to ubuntu - im just receive the whole response straight away. Node version is **19.5** on both servers.
The only diff is that im using Https on prod server
*Also Idk if it's connected or not, I receive **304** on my relogin POST request and **201** on the same request on my localhost*

**My frontend code:**

```
try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${domainConfig.BACKEND_DOMAIN_NAME}/v1/embedding/ask`,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(body),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
      );
      if (response.body) {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition
        while (true) {
          const { done, value } = await reader.read();
          if (done) {
            break;
          }
          const text = new TextDecoder().decode(value);
          setCurrentAnswer((prevState) => prevState + text);
        }
        setIsBotAnswering(false);
        setButtonLoading(false);
      }
```

**My backend code:**

```
import { Response } from 'express';
export const queryPineconeVectorStoreAndQueryLLM = async (
  ...,
  res: Response,
): Promise<void> => {

const result = await llm.call(
        prompt,
      undefined,
      [
        {
          handleLLMNewToken(token: string) {
            res.write(token);
          },
        },
      ],
    );
    }
```

Tried reinstalling node_modules and rebuilding & changing node version on ubuntu to 18. Didnt help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my nginx configuration. Needed to add one line of code

```
proxy_buffering off;
```